# Python object returning integer/float on object reference

Tags: python, oop, object, reference

I have a class like so:

```
class NumberGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, seed=0):
       random.seed(seed)
       self.current = random.random()

    def __next__(self):
        self.next()

    def next(self):
        self.current = random.random()
        return self.current
```

Ideally, I would like to do the following via some magic method if available.

```
>>> numGen = NumberGenerator(99)
>>> numGen.next()
0.15
>>> numGen + 2
2.15
```

I know `__str__` and `__repr__` and `__add__` etc. But what I want is a magic method to return something whenever the object is referenced other than a pointer to the object. I will not assign another variable to the object reference, downstream, I promise. Is this available in Python?

Comment: "But what I want is a magic method to return something whenever the object is referenced other than a pointer to the object." No pointers are returned. Python doesn't have pointers. Fundamentally, you cannot do this. `some_var` is always a reference to an object.

Comment: For your purpose, you might be able to get away with overloading the `+` operator. It's `__add__` that you must override.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay, and how is that reference implemented in Python, if it's not a pointer to the object?

Comment: @neo4k the implementation details are irrelevant, there are no pointers in the Python. It is best to stick to the semantics of the language, unless you are actually interested in the implementation details of a particular implementation.

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig yeah, but what if I want to do `x = numGen; y = x + 2;`

Comment: @neo4k then using the `__add__` hook should work, no? How would it fail to work as you'd expect?

Comment: @neo4k That will work (assuming you want to return a new `NumberGenator` object) if you overload `__add__`.

Comment: @ChristianDean @DanielRoseman I will try playing with `__add__`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "the implementation details are irrelevant, there are no pointers in the Python" so you said, but http://scottlobdell.me/2013/08/understanding-python-variables-as-pointers/ explicitly states "All python references are, in effect, C pointers under the hood."

I don't understand why you contradicted me calling them pointers, when in fact they are so? :D

Comment: @neo4k Note the phrase _"under the hood"_. The statement is simply saying that the _C code that implements Python uses pointers_. This doesn't mean the Python language itself has pointers, only that the language Python is implemented in - C - has pointers.

Comment: @ChristianDean I simply said, "But what I want is a magic method to return something whenever the object is referenced other than a pointer to the object." which is technically correct via the following syllogism: C has pointers. CPython is built in C. CPython has pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python language doesn't include pointers. You can think of variables in Python as references to some object. When using a variable, you're accessing the *object* the variable is referring to.

The behavior you want your `NumberGenerator` class to have, can be implemented by implementing the `__add__` magic method. This is the method Python calls when the `+` operator is being used with an instance of your class on the left side of the expression. In other words:

```
numGen + 2
```

Is translated to:

```
numGen.__add__(2)
```

Note that if you want to use the `+` operator regardless of which side of the expression your class instance is on, you need to also implement the `__radd__` magic method:

```
class NumberGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, seed=0):
       random.seed(seed)
       self.current = random.random()

    def __next__(self):
        self.next()

    def next(self):
        self.current = random.random()
        return self.current

    def __add__(self, value):
        return self.current + value

    def __radd__(self, value):
        return self.__add__(value)
```

Here is an example of the class being used:

```
>>> numGen = NumberGenerator(99)
>>> numGen.next()
0.20007544457494542
>>> numGen + 2
2.2000754445749453
>>> 2 + numGen
2.2000754445749453
>>>
```